# $and of mongodb not working properly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have written one mongodb query using `$and`, but it seems that it is not giving result.

Query:

```
db.getCollection("dummy").find({
  $and: [
    { "RDSON.Max.": { $gte: "0.00112" } },
    { "RDSON.Max": { $lte: "0.00168" } }
  ]
});
```

So I ran the conditions separately to verify whether data is there to satisfy the conditions:

1. `db.getCollection('dummy').find({"RDSON.Max":{ $lte: "0.00168"}})`
   gave 2 records
2. `db.getCollection('dummy').find({"RDSON.Max":{ $gte: "0.00112"}})`
   gave 20 records

Hence I should be getting 2 records when I am using `$and` operator, but it is not working.

Comment: Notice the extraneous period in the first condition of the `$and`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @robertklep I already wasted my 2 hours because of this silly mistake